# Generate permutations of a list of lists with variable lengths

Tags: python

I am looking to generate all of the possible combinations of characters where each position in the list of characters may or may not have multiple choices.

For example, if I have the list `[['A','G'],['A','C','G'],'T']` I would like to generate from it `['AAT','ACT','AGT','GAT','GCT','GGT']`. What is the best way to go about this? I have used itertools in the past but I don't see how any of the functions can handle this sort of request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.product()`:

```
from itertools import product

lsts = [['A', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G'], 'T']
output = [''.join(combo) for combo in product(*lsts)]
```

The `*lsts` syntax applies each element in `lsts` as a separate argument to the `products()` function; as if you called `product(['A', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G'], 'T')`.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lsts = [['A','G'],['A','C','G'],'T']
>>> [''.join(combo) for combo in product(*lsts)]
['AAT', 'ACT', 'AGT', 'GAT', 'GCT', 'GGT']
```

You could reduce your nested lists to strings for the same output:

```
lsts = ['AG', 'ACG','T']
```

or, for consistency's sake, make the last element a list:

```
lsts = [['A', 'G'], ['A', 'C', 'G'], ['T']]
```

but it'll work with the mixed sequences too.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't quite clear how to use product here. Why is the asterisk next to lsts?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make your list homogeneous (list of lists) by using `['T']` instead of `'T'`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> L = [['A','G'],['A','C','G'],['T']]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(*L)]
['AAT', 'ACT', 'AGT', 'GAT', 'GCT', 'GGT']
```

Iterating the string `'T'` does also work, but it's likely to cause other bugs in my experience